# Validation on a partial class

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, validation

I have this code for validation of the Customer class which is created from a WCF service:

```
public partial class Customer : IDataErrorInfo
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }

#region IDataErrorInfo Members

public string Error
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        string result = null;
        if (columnName == "FirstName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
                result = "Please enter a First Name";
        }
        if (columnName == "LastName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
                result = "Please enter a Last Name";
        }
       if (columnName == "Age")
        {
            if (Age < = 0 || Age >= 99)
                result = "Please enter a valid age";
        }
        return result;
    }
}

#endregion
```

}

I get the error at the definition of the this[string columnName] method, probably because its a partial class:

```
Member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
```

Do you know how I can get around this problem?

Comment: What has the other side of the partial class got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this is telling you, is that your Member name cannot be the same name as the class name. For example you cannot have a Customer method or property on a Customer object.

For example beware of

```
public class Customer 
{
   public void Customer()  //<- You cannot do this, remove the void Customer should only be the constructor
   { } 
}
```

So I'm guessing that the issue is somewhere else and not int the code snippet that you have posted.